# How to filter the result of FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots() in order to get the path of sd card only?

Tags: codenameone

I try to use

```
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots()
```

to get roots of sd card which can write public file, but my device it returns 2 paths:

```
/storage/sdcard0
/system
```

I want to write on /storage/sdcard0 only, how can I force to choose the path of sd card? I can't find any other methods to return roots of storage, can I hardcode the first element of array in result as sd card path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `FileSystemStorage` syntax:

```
if(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRootType(currentRoot) == FileSystemStorage.ROOT_TYPE_SDCARD) {

   ...
}
```

Using new [CN syntax](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/static-global-context.html):

```
if(getFileSystemRootType(currentRoot) == FileSystemStorage.ROOT_TYPE_SDCARD) {

   ...
}
```

Although we should probably add ROOT_TYPE_SDCARD to CN too.